# Fast computing solution to calculate number of rows matching a vector value

Tags: r

I am trying to create by specifying a dataframe and the columns used, a dataframe that would be a grid of all the possible combination of the levels of the columns selected. I also add a variable, T_weight, initialized at 0.001 to avoid problem of case not selected for future treatments, which counts for the different combinations the number of times they appear in the original dataframe.

Here is the code I am using and a simple example :

```
Grid_from_df <- function(df,inputs,true_weights=F){
  df_levels <- sapply(df[,inputs],levels)
  print(df_levels)
  grid_df <- expand.grid(df_levels)
  print(grid_df)
  grid_df$F_weight <- rep(1,nrow(grid_df))
  if (true_weights){
    grid_df$T_weight <- rep(0.001,nrow(grid_df))
    for (i in 1:nrow(grid_df)){
      sel <- t(apply(df[,inputs],1,function(row) grid_df[i,inputs] == row))
      sel2 <- apply(sel,1,function(row) sum(row)==length(row))
      grid_df[i,"T_weight"] <- grid_df[i,"T_weight"] + sum(sel2)
    }
  }
  return(grid_df)
}

df2 <- data.frame(X1=c(1,2,2,1),X2=c(2,2,1,1),X3=c(3,4,5,3))
df2$X1 <- as.factor(df2$X1)
df2$X2 <- as.factor(df2$X2)
df2$X3 <- as.factor(df2$X3)
df3 <- Grid_from_df(df2,c("X1","X2","X3"),T)
```

Even though it seems to be working on this simple example, the processing time to calculate T_weight is extremely long for the size of dataframes of my project (about 10 variables, and 300 000 rows).

Since I am rather limited in R, I was wondering if someone had a faster solution to calculate T_weight, maybe without using a for loop.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your ideal answer:

A `dataframe` where a combination (1,2,3) appear twice

```
df2 <- data.frame(X1=c(1,2,2,1,1),X2=c(2,2,1,1,2),X3=c(3,4,5,3,3)) 
library(data.table)
df2 <- data.table(df2)
df2$T_weigth <- 1
```

This collapses the group and calculate the number of time they appear

```
df2 <- df2[, list(T_weigth=sum(T_weigth)), by=c("X1", "X2", "X3")]
```

Create the new dataframe with all the combination ( here I use CJ (cross joint) from package data.table because it is known to be fast)

```
dt_temp = df2[, do.call(CJ, c(.SD, unique=TRUE)), .SDcols=c("X1", "X2", "X3")]
```

Merge with the original data to get the weight associate to the correct combination and replace the `NA` weight with 0 (again with data.table)

```
df3 <- merge(dt_temp, df2,by=colnames(dt_temp), all.x=TRUE)[, T_weigth := ifelse(is.na(T_weigth),0, T_weigth )]
```

If you do it this way with the `base` package, it should work also, and be faster than your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, way faster than what  I was using. T_weight is supposed to be an information about the number of time the profile appear in the original base. The ideal answer to my problem would contain each possible profile once, T_weight indicating the number of times this profile appears in the original database

Comment: @J.Tristan I edit the answer so you have your ideal answer.

Comment: Thank you, the discovery of the data.table type has made my day. It seems initializing to 1 then making a sum by the keys can be replaced by a T_weight := .N during the creation of df2. I also added a unique(df3)  at the end of the code for more complex examples where multiple rows with the same profiles may appear, to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: @J.Tristan If you use `T_weight := .N`, then your are not collapsing but only counting. That's why you need `unique(df3)` at the end. With the `list(T_weight=sum(T_weight))`, You do not have duplicates, so no need of `unique`. I can not say what is faster, but it make more sens for me the collapse the data first. Anyway, if you use `unique`, use is on `df2` instead of `df3`, this should be faster